# How to impersonate windows authenticated login user without password in c#

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, impersonation

How to impersonate user without password in windows authentication application c#?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It sounds like a major security issue!

Comment: Create a dummy user account to do your testing or use your own account.

Comment: I need to run the application with specific user, but the application is taking service account only cache is not clearing after login other user in windows authentication.

Answer (score 1):

All users have passwords.

From your comments on the main thread, you mention that the application is taking only a service account. This is not uncommon.

In an ideal scenario, your organization will have created a separate service account specifically for testing. The name and password for that account will be known to the development team, so that they can be provided during development and testing.

If this is not the case, you may be using a production user account, and it becomes difficult to distinguish between activity performed during development and release.